# Is $\nabla \cdot (\mathbf{a} \mathbf{b}^\mathrm{T}) = \mathbf{b}(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{a})+(\mathbf{a}\cdot \nabla) \mathbf{b}$ correct?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Wikipedia says that the following statement is a vector identity:

$$\nabla \cdot (\mathbf{a} \mathbf{b}^\mathrm{T}) = \mathbf{b}(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{a})+(\mathbf{a}\cdot \nabla) \mathbf{b}$$

Where $\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}^\mathrm{T}$ is the outer product of $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$. Therefore, it is a matrix! Now my question is this:

How can we define the inner product of the operator $\nabla$ that is treated like a vector with a matrix!? Their dimensions don't match, so, the inner product in the classical sense is meaningless here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\nabla \cdot M$ is abuse of notation for the per-column divergence of $M$. Assuming $M$ has dimension $n\times n$ and your metric is Euclidean:

$$(\nabla \cdot M)_i = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial m_{ji}}{\partial x_j}.$$

The intuition here is that you can treat the nabla operator like a "vector" $\nabla = \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\ldots \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\right]^T$ in which case the above formula is what you would get from applying ordinary rules of vector-matrix multiplication to the "inner product" $\nabla^T M$. This shortcut works since $\nabla$, like multiplication by a matrix, acts linearly, but of course one should be careful when relying on such notational tricks. Your identity is a great example; naive manipulation would not correctly recover the second term of the chain rule:
$$(\nabla^T a b^T)^T \neq b (a^T \nabla) = b (\nabla \cdot a).$$

Comment: So, why would we need to define such a thing? It's definitely not an inner product in the usual sense that we expect. Why would anyone define such a thing then? I mean where is it used?

Comment: Taking the divergence of tensors arises naturally in a lot of physics applications. For instance, the net internal force acting at a point on an elastic surface is $\nabla \cdot \sigma$ where $\sigma$ is the $2\times 2$ surface stress tensor.

Comment: Oh, I see. So, divergence can be defined for all tensor fields, not only vector fields! And the use of dot product is simply because we use the same notation for vector fields. Right? Does the divergence of a tensor with rank higher than 1 have an intuitive meaning?

Comment: Yes, you can take the divergence of arbitrarily high-rank tensors in the same way: take the gradient w.r.t. one dimension and then contract. I don't know an example off-hand but I'm sure it arises in 3D elasticity, for instance.

Comment: In the definition of per column divergence of a matrix, we first take the transpose of $M$ and then contract with respect to the rows of $M^{\mathrm{T}}$. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Things become more transparent if we work in index notation. Note that to take the divergence of a matrix $M$ returns a vector with components $(\nabla\cdot M)_j =\sum_i \partial_i M_{i j}$. In the case of $M_{i j}=(\mathbf{a} \mathbf{b}^T)_{ij}=a_i b_j$ this yields

$$\left(\nabla\cdot (\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}^T)\right)_j= \sum_i \partial_i (a_i b_j)=b_j\left(\sum_i \partial_i a_i\right)+\left(\sum_i a_i \partial_i\right)b_j=\left(\mathbf{b}\left(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{a}\right)+(\mathbf{a}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{b}\right)_j$$

Comment: Yes, the proof of the identity is easy once you know the definition of the divergence of a matrix, but I don't get why anyone would define such a thing and then use the dot product notation for it! Where is the divergence of a matrix used?